# Open file relative to executed module

Tags: c++, io, relative-path, ifstream

I know, it isn't the best idea to open a file constraining it to be placed in the same directory like the executed module. But, there is a tool, I was ordered to program, with exact these specification.

There is a parameter for the file path which could be the absolute path to the file or just the file name assuming it is located in the current directory.

I don't want to use the WinAPI function GetCurrentDirectory in order to retain portability. The tool should fail if the file couldn't be opened.

Usually I'm using boost::filesystem as I/O-library. Thus, I'm not very familiar with std-library.

My first idea was to just pass the file path to std::ifstream::open(). But it seems this isn't working for relative paths.

What can I do to cover my requirement?

Comment: You start out talking about opening files that live in the same directory as the executable. Then you talk about the current directory. Those aren't necessarily identical. In fact, I'd even say it *rare* for the current directory of a command-line program to be the same as the program's own directory. Please clarify which you really need.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no easily portable way to do this. In particular, `GetCurrentDirectory` may not return the same directory as your executable module - on windows, simply opening a common dialog file selection box will result in your current directory changing! On other platforms, you're not likely to start out in the same directory at all (then again, you might not have write access there either, but that applies to modern windows too...)

On windows, in general, you'll want to use `GetModuleFileName` to find your module's location, then strip off the filename portion. On Linux, call `readlink` on `/proc/self/exe` for the main executable, or munge around in `/proc/self/maps` for the mapping corresponding to your code segment for a dynamic library. On other OSes, I have no idea.

Comment: You are right. I already know that, but like I said. I hoped that I don't need to use WinAPI.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: Write your own function to get the file name, which you implement differently on Windows and on Linux (and even elsewhere).  Then you maintain portability via your thin wrapper.  However, especially on non-Windows systems, you should consider better ideas; you seem to know using the executable's location is a rather poor solution from what you indicated in the question.

Comment: @Fred Nurk - Constraing the file to be located in the same folder like the executable is part of my specification. Thus, I mentioned that, but ... ;)

Comment: @FrEEzE2046: I know you did; I'd encourage you to get that changed. :)

Answer (score -3):

Just pass the relative file name. It will be taken relative to the current directory.

Comment: Current directories change far too much on windows. The open file dialog box, for example, changes the current directory on you, even across threads. You should _never_ use the current directory on win32 for this very reason.

Comment: That's the question. Does std::ifstream handle relative file paths or not?

Comment: The very existence of relative paths is not part of the C++ standard :) In general, it is _not portable_ to assume you're going to start out in the same directory as your executable. And it is simply _not true_ that will will remain there.

Comment: (That said, on windows, all standard C or C++ I/O functions will handle relative paths - but please, please, don't use them for this)

Comment: Okay, so, it's implementation specific. Is there any possibility to get the name of the current module or do I need to hard-code the name when using GetModuleHandle()?

Comment: Thinking about that ... I will use the module handle passed to my DllMain ;)

Comment: The requirement was "current directory". Passing the relative file name will do that. So I don't see the reason for the -1...

Comment: If "that's the question," Freeze, then why didn't you *say so* when you asked? And @Bdonlan, if we shouldn't use relative paths because the standard doesn't include them, then shouldn't we also not use absolute paths? The standard doesn't say anything about file *paths* at all.

Comment: @Rob, we shouldn't use relative paths in windows because there are too many things that change the current directory implicitly. The open file dialog is a good example; just browsing will change the current directory. It's also not particularly threadsafe, being shared across all threads in the process.  Depending on the shortcut's configuration you might not start out in the app directory either, and if files are dragged into your app's icon you'll start in that file's directory, I believe. If you're careful it might be possible to use it safely, but there are just too many pitfalls.